# Php Import Script for an excel values import and showing line by line updates

Tags: php, import

I just want to import an excel file to populate my product section in my website ( its like importing products through excel as in magento ) . I am able to upload excel file and read data line by line and insert the validated values into my database. but the problem is I just want to show line by line validation errors or success message( on insertion). How to achieve this.(As you may have seen in magento when we import data, it shows line by line update ie errors and success messages on the browser) . But my code is not in magento. I am developing it in Codeigniter. Its just a custom made website.

So please tell me How can i show every line updates ( errors/success messages) on browser during the values are read and updated/inserted in the database.

Comment: why vote -2 to this post ? whats wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2):

Simply call [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush) after sending data to the client. This causes PHP to clear its output buffer and send it to the webserver which then sends it to the client.